# Updating Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, flutter

Im trying to mix a map with a side menu , 
but I am having an error on Debug Console which returns me as "Gradle Error"

I already tried to updtade the gradle (but i did not make it)
and i tried to update de version of google maps and geolocator, my code 
my code showed errors after that

Error on the Debug:

- Error running Gradle:
  ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\Duarte\Desktop\Feasy BKP\BACKUP PRINCIPAL\Feasy_Mapa_1.5\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

> Configure project :app
>   WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variant.getMergeAssets(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
>   WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
>
> Configure project :geolocator
>   WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.3.2.
>   Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
>   To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
>
> Configure project :google_api_availability
>   WARNING: API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variant.getJavaCompile(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.0 and higher.
  The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
  project ':google_api_availability' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
  Command: C:\Users\Duarte\Desktop\Feasy BKP\BACKUP PRINCIPAL\Feasy_Mapa_1.5\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 0):

please check your project structure and try changing the SDK version.and build tool also.
because some of the gradle versions are not applicable with SKD's version.